# Given a simple graph with $n = 4k + 2$ vertices. Can the vertices of this graph have distinct degrees?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I was given this question that asks: Given a simple graph with $n = 4k + 2$ vertices. Can the vertices of
this graph have distinct degrees?

I was wondering how I would go about this. I am usually provided a graph as a visual but I am confused with this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

- The degrees would have to be the integers $0,1,\ldots,4k+1$: why?
- What is the sum of the degrees?
- Now consider the handshake lemma.

Comment: Wouldn't the degrees be the integers from 0,1,......,4k+2?

Comment: @Micky: No: that’s a set of $4k+3$ numbers, and you have only $4k+2$ vertices. Besides, the graph is simple, so no vertex is connected to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a simple graph has $X$ vertices where $X>1$ and each vertex has a distinct degree.
The degrees must be between $0$ and $X-1$ inclusive as the graph is simple.
This means that the degrees must be $0,1,2,...,X-1$ but then the vertex with degree 0 has no neighbours. However, the vertex with degree $X-1$ is connected to every other vertex, including the vertex with degree $0$. This is a contradiction.
If $n=4k+2$ for some non-negative integer $k$ then $n\ge4\times0+2=2$
so $n>1$ and therefore a graph where each vertex has a distinct degree does not exist.